# Scene Builder 2 JavaFX2 button issue

Tags: button, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I feel like I'm missing something easy but I'm not sure what it is. Here is my code:

```
@FXML
    private Label label;
    private Button startGameButton;

    @FXML
    private void startGame (ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Ok. Let's begin.");
        startGameButton.setVisible(false);
    }
```

I made a button in Scene Builder and set its **fx:id** to **startGameButton**. I'm just trying to make the **startGameButton** disappear when I click on it. I thought this would be sufficient but I'm getting a

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myjavafx2.FXMLDocumentController.startGame(FXMLDocumentController.java:29)
```

I feel as though the NullPointerException is telling me the button doesn't exist but I made it in Scene Builder. I don't think I would need to do `Button startGameButton = new Button();` because Scene Builder should be doing that for me. What am I missing?

Comment: if you are using NetBeans then use make controller option to create the controller files. It will take care of all the FXML injection and annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `@FXML` before your `Button` as well.
Like this:

```
@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private Button startGameButton;

@FXML
private void startGame (ActionEvent event) {
    label.setText("Ok. Let's begin.");
    startGameButton.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I thought it was like Objective-C where you only need one "heading" for the variables. It worked perfectly after adding the @FXML above the startGameButton.